# Request Timeout This request takes too long to process, 'Connection Timeout'

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, request

I have wordpress blog and its been open 5 days.After 5 days I cant open web site.I see this warning.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This solution is for Litespeed

Add in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1]
```

[Litespeed Doc](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:php:run-without-timeouts)

Comment: Nice one. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you made any recent changes then back them out. If that does not resolve the issue then you need to start debugging your stack.

1. Check your host to make sure that webserver is up?
2. Check to see if you have any errors in your PHP logs?
3. Ceck that your database is up and functional. You can check if the DB is accepting connections by doing a telnet to the mysql (I am assuming mysql) port. Command without quotes is "telnet MYDBHOST 3306"

These three things above will lead you in the direction of the true problem.